# How to compare firebase inner child items in android without data object model?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to validate the admin by taking text from the app. I've tried using a data object model and store the details but it is just not required. I've tried this code in other classes without the loop and it works fine.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Preschools");
                        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for(DataSnapshot preschool : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        for(DataSnapshot admin : preschool.getChildren())
                                        {
                                                String f_em = (String) admin.child("Admin").child("Email").getValue();
                                                String f_pa = (String) admin.child("Admin").child("Password").getValue();
                                                if(emailAddress.getText().toString().equals(f_em) && password.getText().toString().equals(f_pa))
                                                {
                                                    flag = true;
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(_2_Login.this, "Unable to reach firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Logacat : [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDYO5.png)

False is returned in the if condition. I'm not able to figure out the error in my logic.

Comment: You want to veify that condition, for a particular preschool (i.e. Bright Kid Test) or for all preschools?

Comment: For all the preschools. My login page is the same for the preschool,admin and the user. So the admin side validation is done here. I've answered this question. The error - no break if condition was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error : No break if credentials are equal.
Below is the correct code:

```
                            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Preschools");
                        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for(DataSnapshot preschool : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        if(emailAddress.getText().toString().equals(preschool.child("Admin").child("Email").getValue()) &&
                                                password.getText().toString().equals(preschool.child("Admin").child("Password").getValue()))
                                               {flag=true; break;}
                                    }
```